# Bug in Visual Studio 2015(Enterprise) ?!(using name property)

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, visual-studio-2015, panel, stackpanel

The error causing code:

```
 <StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button"/>
    <Button Height="277" Name="button1">
        <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Inhalt im Button"></TextBlock>
                <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Width="184"/>
                <Image x:Name="image" Height="180" Source=...0_2445832832163420875_n.jpg" Width="247"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

This gives me an error:

```
   <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button"/>
        <Button Height="277" >         
            <Button.Name>
                button1
            </Button.Name>
            <Button.Content>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Inhalt im Button"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Width="184"/>
                    <Image x:Name="image" Height="180" Source="..97186010_2445832832163420875_n.jpg" Width="247"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

Using `<Button.Name>button1</Button.Name>` will cause an Error(in Visual Studio 2013 it works without any problems.).

The error message:

> Error     Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel' to
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Button'  WpfTree  Error  CS0029  Cannot
>   implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel' to
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Button'  WpfTree

Comment: while debugging, it seems that it's trying to assign the content of the button to the button field in the generated code. Since the content of your button is a stack panel, it's trying to assign that to the button field:

this.button1 = ((System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel)(target));
which fails since button1 is of type Button.
This may indeed be a bug.

Comment: I notice that all the other Name attributes have an "x" namespace (ie. x:Name)... does changing your button Name to x:Name make any difference?